# "django.core.exceptions.ValidationError" error

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

I am writing a simple game in Django, all of things were right, but suddenly..., I was encountered by following error:

- Django.v = 1.7
- Python.v = 3.4

I don't know what is wrong with these codes:

```
    (test)alireza@alireza:~/test/test1$ python manage.py syncdb
    Operations to perform:
      Synchronize unmigrated apps: django_admin_bootstrapped, django_admin_bootstrapped_bootstrap3, crispy_forms
      Apply all migrations: contenttypes, admin, auth, arosis, sessions
    Synchronizing apps without migrations:
      Creating tables...
      Installing custom SQL...
      Installing indexes...
    Running migrations:
      Applying arosis.0008_auto_20150212_0826...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-
...
...
...

        return self.to_python(value)
      File "/home/alireza/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1252, in to_python
        params={'value': value},
    django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

## In my models.py:

```
class Move(models.Model):
    """docstring for Move"""
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    by_first_player = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.comment)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'timestamp'

    def player(self):
        return self.game.first_player if self.by_first_player else self.game.second_player
```

I gave 
`auto_now_add=True`,

but at first, when I run :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

It asked me for entering a default value for `DateTimeField()`

***What should I do?***

## 0008_auto_20150212_0826.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('arosis', '0007_auto_20150211_1844'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='move',
            options={'get_latest_by': 'timestamp'},
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='move',
            name='by_first_player',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='move',
            name='timestamp',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default='', auto_now_add=True),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar thing. Delete all migrations from your folder /migrations and then run python manage.py makemigrations  and then python manage.py migrate. This worked for me.

Comment: OMG I spent 4 hours bashing my head against the wall. THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: that's cool in some cases, but what to do when you don't want to delete all data? how to fix just this one column with invalid data?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you already have a database which already has some "Move" entries in it.

If you add a column in a table which already has data in it, you'll need to provide a default value for that column, that the migration will set to all existing entries in the DB for the involved table (otherwise such entries will be invalid, unless null=True is specified as kwarg, if I remember correctly)

Furthermore, it is possible (happens to me ALL THE TIME), that you will need to set, in settings.py, the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS and the DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS variables, accordingly to your locale and the way you're used to type dates.
(See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)

An example (In Italy, we have DD/MM/YYYY format):

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ( "%d/%m/%Y", )
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ( "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", )
```

You django configuration is expecting the following format instead:

```
 YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]
```

(Stuff inside the square brackets is optional)

Edit: the auto_now_add kw arg tells that the field value should be set to "now" when adding (and not updating..) an entry

Comment: Hi @Alessandro, I am doing anything with it and even I clear all of my models.py classes, but nothing :( I don't know what's wrong!

Comment: Are you asked to input a default value when migrating? What do you type in when you're asked for a default value? You need to provide a valid date in the format django expects

Comment: Can you post the 0008_auto_20150212_0826.py migration?

Comment: Yes, I type ' ' (blank) when migrating asked me.

Comment: I added 0008_auto ...py to the main question.

Comment: As I told you, you will need to provide a valid date when asked, instead of ''.

The date you provide MUST be a valid date in the format django expects, which in your case is the default (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]).


If you want to allow the timestamp field to be empty, add the blank=True option to the DateTimeField. It that case, you can set '' (blank) as date.

Comment: Really Thanks :) It got fixed by following your command. I was being bewildered and I couldn't think.

Answer (score 0):

> It asked me for entering a default value for DateTimeField()

It is doing this because you have not specified a default, and the field is not optional. Since its a destructive change, you have to provide a default value.

You probably just hit enter and hence the exception, since a blank string is not a valid entry for `DateTimeField`.

The solution is to run migrate again, and this time provide a valid date and time string; which will be used for all existing rows in your database; example of a valid format is `2015-02-12 00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're not afraid of getting your hands a little dirty, looking through the migrations files in that folder and finding the specific invalid field did it for me.
Deleting all the migrations threw  up a few errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (if you are using Visual Studio Code and you don't want to delete all files from the `migrations` folder):

Press **ctr+shift+f**

type the phrase that was seen as invalid.

For example:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“09.09.2022” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
```

so type **09.09.2022**

**Be sure that you are looking at all files!**

Below the 'search' field, place in the 'replace' field a proper date: **2022.09.09**

voila