# I keep getting an "Invalid Format" error when creating Python Models with timestamps

Tags: python, django, timestamp

Hey guys I'm creating a basic app and it was running fine until I created a new table with my Models.py file that had a timestamp.  My NewPost model already had the Timestamp and that was working fine.  However, when I run migrate (makemigrations runs OK) I'm now getting a weird error in the console that the format is not correct and I'm unable to start my app.

I delete the timestamp fields, and I'm still getting the error!  Can someone help me figure out what to do?  Below is the error and my Models.py code.  If you need any more code let me know.  Thanks!

Models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class User(AbstractUser):
    userRanking = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class NewPost(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="movies")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="Hi", null="True")
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
class Vote(models.Model):
    postID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    userID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upVotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downVotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Reply(models.Model):
    postID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Error Message in Console:

```
C:\school\project4>python manage.py migrate network
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: network
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying network.0001_initial... OK
  Applying network.0002_auto_20201119_1427... OK
  Applying network.0003_auto_20201119_1435... OK
  Applying network.0004_auto_20201119_1438... OK
  Applying network.0005_auto_20201119_1451... OK
  Applying network.0006_auto_20201122_1812... OK
  Applying network.0007_auto_20201124_1159... OK
  Applying network.0008_auto_20201124_1557... OK
  Applying network.0009_auto_20201207_1206... OK
  Applying network.0010_newpost_category... OK
  Applying network.0011_newpost_title... OK
  Applying network.0012_auto_20201207_1341... OK
  Applying network.0013_auto_20201207_1931... OK
  Applying network.0014_newpost_rating... OK
  Applying network.0015_reply... OK
  Applying network.0016_auto_20201208_1559...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 110, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 189, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 821, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1376, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1355, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1215, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1337, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a PostgreSQL specific field (`django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField`) with SQLite?

Comment: I deleted the import line and I still get the same error.  Any idea what to do?

Comment: this post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473923/django-core-exceptions-validationerror-error/31364804

Comment: Honestly I didn't think that the error was caused by the import line; I was simply pointing out that it doesn't make sense. It is hard to say anything without seeing the database and the previous state of your model but try adding `blank=True` to your `timestamp` column.

Comment: Selcuk - Nope I tried that and I'm still getting the same error.  I deleted the database and started anew and it still won't start.  I currently can't get python manage.py runserver to work no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the migrations folder and the database and run makemigrations and migrate again and it works!